# Máscara de percentual no angular

Tags: angular

Como posso fazer uma máscara de percentual usando angular 2+?

Quero aplicá-la no meu input:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="produto.indice_lucro" name="indicelucro" id="indicelucro" class="form-control">
<label for="indicelucro">Índice de Lucro (%)</label> <i matTooltip="Qual o percentual de lucro que você deseja lucrar com a venda desse produto?" class="fa fa-info-circle informacao" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Eu pensei em usar um pipe no meu value:

```
<input type="text" value="produto.indice_lucro | percent">
```

Não funcionou bem e não consegui encontrar um tutorial que ensinasse percentual.

Comment: como é essa máscara que você quer? mostra um exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar *pipes* do Angular 6 é preciso que utilize a *bind* correta de dados. Como explicado na [documentação](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe), é necessário que o valor da variável seja um número e que seja utilizado a notação `{{ value | percent}}`. No seu caso seria algo como:

`<input type="text" [value]="{{ produto.indice_lucro | percent }}">`

É possível utilizar localização e quantidades de casas antes e depois da vírgula também, como parâmetro da propriedade *percent*.

```
b: number = 1.3495;
<p>B: {{b | percent:'4.3-5':'fr'}}</p>
Output: 0 134,950 %
```